# function imagewebp doesn't exist in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, gd, webp, php-5.5, php-5.6

PHP-File:

```
<?php
echo phpversion();
echo "\n";
var_dump(function_exists('imagewebp'));
```

Output:

```
5.6.0RC2
bool(false)
```

GD Support is enabled (GD Version:bundled (2.1.0 compatible))

---

Where is the problem? "imagewebp" should exist since PHP 5.5.0 (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php)

PS: (I'm not the only one... [How to compile php to enable webp support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786201/how-to-compile-php-to-enable-webp-support))

Comment: Is the GD library installed and enabled?

Comment: @john-conde How can I check this?

Comment: If GD does show up in the `phpinfo()` and that function doesn't exist, I would expect it to be a bug with the release candidate that [you should report](https://bugs.php.net/).

Comment: Have you tried going up to 5.6.0 GA release? RC2 is several months old

Comment: @alex-w I created a bug-report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67999