# How to enable support for module in PHP.ini

Tags: php, apache, gd

The function `imagecreatefromwebp()` does not exist in my `php(GD)` library. `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and other functions work fine. I need to enable something specific to `imagecreatefromwebp()`.

GD2 is already installed on Debian with some of the modules installed.

**How do I enable support for imagecreatefromwebp()?**

1. Can I enable it just by adding a directive or something in php.ini?
2. Or Do I need to install the additional Module? How do I do it individually?
3. OR Do I need to re install php again with all necessary modules?

EDIT: This link seems helpful->http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php couldn't understand it completely, it seems specifically for the (new)installation

phpinfo():GD
[image]

Comment: what GD version do you have?

Comment: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

Comment: ok, good
so you got Call to undefined function: imagecreatefromwebp(), right?

Comment: yes, that is correct; looks like while installation `--with-vpx-dir=DIR`  was not used

Comment: seems so, anyway can you share the result of gd_info() function?

Comment: `["GD Version"]=>  string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["FreeType Linkage"]=>  string(13) "with freetype"
  ["T1Lib Support"]=>  bool(false)
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["XBM Support"]=>  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>  bool(false)`

Comment: уes, seems that it wasn't configured right during installation, as you said. Try remove GD and build it again with webp support

Answer (score 1):

I was researched in the web and the answer is you should reinstall php again with --with-vpx-dir=DIR option.

Please see this question, there described probably the same problem as you have

[How to compile php to enable webp support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786201/how-to-compile-php-to-enable-webp-support)