# How can I add WebP support to a php7.2 install in a amazon linux 2 box?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, gd, webp

In a new amazon linux2 box I ran the following:

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2`

`sudo yum install php-gd`

But then when I run:

`php -r 'var_dump(gd_info());'`

I get:

`array(13) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["FreeType Linkage"]=>
  string(13) "with freetype"
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WebP Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["BMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}`

I don't know what I have to do to have WebP Support as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I had to compile gd

First I removed the old version
`sudo yum remove php-gd`

then check php version
`php -v`

get the src
`sudo wget https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-7.2.3.tar.gz`

`sudo tar zxf php-7.2.3.tar.gz`

`cd php-src-php-7.2.3/ext/gd/`

I had to install these 
`sudo yum install php-devel gd-devel libwebp-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel`

`sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

`sudo yum install libwebp-devel libjpeg-devel libpng-devel zlib-devel libXpm-devel`

`sudo phpize`

`sudo ./configure --with-jpeg-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-webp-dir --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir`

`sudo make`

`sudo cp modules/gd.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/`

and then edit php.ini to enable 
`sudo nano /etc/php.ini`

add
`extension=gd`

then it is available
`php -m`

`php -r 'var_dump(gd_info());'`

`array(13) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["FreeType Linkage"]=>
  string(13) "with freetype"
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WebP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["BMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}`

Comment: Thanks so much! The only answer that helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to compile gd.so from source with **WebP Support**.

**GD** was already there, **WebP Support** was/is missing.

Possible Duplicate: [How to compile php to enable webp support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786201/how-to-compile-php-to-enable-webp-support)

You also may use a free image service to do this work for you.

https://www.cloudinary.com/

https://cloudconvert.com/

https://uploadcare.com/

https://www.imghaste.com/

or even convert them offline:
https://www.imghaste.com/converter